# how to fit a step function in python

Tags: python, scipy

I have a question about fitting a step function using scipy routines like curve_fit. I have trouble making it vectorized, for example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xobs=np.linspace(0,10,100)
yl=np.random.rand(50); yr=np.random.rand(50)+100
yobs=np.concatenate((yl,yr),axis=0)

def model(x,rf,T1,T2):
#1:   x=np.vectorize(x)
    if x<rf:
        ret= T1
    else:
        ret= T2
    return ret
#2: model=np.vectorize(model)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(model, xobs, yobs, [40.,0.,100.])
```

It says

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

If I add #1 or #2 it runs but doesn't really fit the data:

```
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated     category=OptimizeWarning)
[ 40.          50.51182064  50.51182064] [[ inf  inf  inf]
[ inf  inf  inf]
[ inf  inf  inf]]
```

Anybody know how to fix that? THX

Comment: maybe `jobs` --> `yobs` ?

Comment: What does `[40.,0.,100.]` represent ?

Comment: In model function, the comparator (x<rf), is x an array?  If so, that's the source of the truth value error.

Comment: Oh in my code it is yobs... maybe auto-corrected when I pasted here. And [40.,0.,100.] is guessing parameters

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did.  I retained `xobs` and `yobs`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xobs=np.linspace(0,10,100)
yl=np.random.rand(50); yr=np.random.rand(50)+100
yobs=np.concatenate((yl,yr),axis=0)
```

Now, Heaviside function must be generated. To give you an overview of this function, consider the half-maximum convention of Heaviside function:

[image: Heaviside]

In Python, this is equivalent to: `def f(x): return 0.5 * (np.sign(x) + 1)`

A sample plot would be:

```
xval = sorted(np.concatenate([np.linspace(-5,5,100),[0]])) # includes x = 0
yval = f(xval)
plt.plot(xval,yval,'ko-')
plt.ylim(-0.1,1.1)
plt.xlabel('x',size=18)
plt.ylabel('H(x)',size=20)
```

[image: Heaviside2]

Now, plotting `xobs` and `yobs` gives:

```
plt.plot(xobs,yobs,'ko-')
plt.ylim(-10,110)
plt.xlabel('xobs',size=18)
plt.ylabel('yobs',size=20)
```

[image: xobs_yobs]

Notice that comparing the two figures, the second plot is shifted by 5 units and the maximum increases from 1.0 to 100. I infer that the function for the second plot can be represented as follows:

[image: Hfit]

or in Python: `(0.5 * (np.sign(x-5) + 1) * 100 = 50 * (np.sign(x-5) + 1)`

Combining the plots yields (where `Fit` represents the above fitting function)

[image: Heaviside_combined]

The plot confirms that my guess is correct. Now, assuming that YOU DO NOT KNOW how did this correct fitting function come about, a generalized fitting function is created: `def f(x,a,b,c): return a * (np.sign(x-b) + c)`, where theoretically, `a = 50`, `b = 5`, and `c = 1`.

Proceed to estimation:

`popt,pcov=curve_fit(f,xobs,yobs,bounds=([49,4.75,0],[50,5,2]))`.

Now, `bounds = ([lower bound of each parameter (a,b,c)],[upper bound of each parameter])`. Technically, this means that 49 < `a` < 50, 4.75 < `b` < 5, and 0 < `c` < 2.

Here are MY results for `popt` and `pcov`:
[image: Results]

`pcov` represents the estimated covariance of popt. The diagonals provide the variance of the parameter estimate [[Source]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

Results show that the parameter estimates `pcov` are near the theoretical values.

Basically, a generalized Heaviside function can be represented by: `a * (np.sign(x-b) + c)`

Here is the code that will generate parameter estimates and the corresponding covariances:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xobs = np.linspace(0,10,100)
yl = np.random.rand(50); yr=np.random.rand(50)+100
yobs = np.concatenate((yl,yr),axis=0)

def f(x,a,b,c): return a * (np.sign(x-b) + c) # Heaviside fitting function

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f,xobs,yobs,bounds=([49,4.75,0],[50,5,2]))
print 'popt = %s' % popt
print 'pcov = \n %s' % pcov
```

Finally, note that the estimates of `popt` and `pcov` vary.

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy)

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty old, but in case it can be useful to other people: The Heaviside function is not differentiable at the step, and this is causing issues in the minimization. In such cases, I fit a logistic function, as shown below.

Fitting a heaviside function always fails in my case.

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,101)
y = np.heaviside((x-5), 0.) 
def sigmoid(x, x0,b):
    return scipy.special.expit((x-x0)*b)
args, cov = optim.curve_fit(sigmoid, x, y)
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x, sigmoid(x, *args))
print(args)

> 

[  5.05006427 532.21427701]
```

[image: fit step data with a sigmoid]

Answer (score 1):

For noisy and more complex data you can also use the error function to fit the step:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.special import erf
np.random.seed(0)

def func(x,x0,y0,h,a,b=0,c=0):
    return y0 + h/2*erf((x-x0)*a) + b*x + c*x**2

# Generate mock data
x = np.linspace(0,1,200)
y = (x>0.5)*0.2 + 0.1 + np.random.rand(len(x))*0.2 + x*0.3

# Use curvefit
popt,pocv = curve_fit(func,x,y,p0 = (np.nanmean(x),np.min(y),np.max(y)-np.min(y),1.0,1.0))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,func(x,*popt))
```

[image]